# In OpenCV what is the VideoCapture destructor

Tags: c++, opencv

At the link in the documentation for VideoCapture::Release - C++ here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture%3A%3Aread#videocapture-release

it says this line

"The methods are automatically called by subsequent VideoCapture::open() and by VideoCapture destructor."

I was hoping someone could tell me what the VideoCapture  destructor is exactly I googled but got no definitive answer...I'm sure its called automatically at some specified time by the usual VideoCapture functions but if someone could give tell me what it is exactly, when exactly its called and where in the source it is I would be Most Appreciative=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite easy. the destructor will get called, once the object leaves scope.

```
{ // the capture only lives inside those brackets

    VideoCapture cap;
    if ( cap.open() )
    {  
        //... do some work 
    }

} // here it will release itself
```

---

maybe it gets more obvious, if you try with your own class:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass()  { cerr << "created MyClass" << endl; }    // constructor
    ~MyClass() { cerr << "destroyed MyClass" << endl; }  // destructor
};


void foo()
{ // scope starts
    MyClass mc;
    int z=17;
    z *= 3;
    cerr << z << endl;
} // scope ends, mc will get destroyed.

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructor is a method of a class, which is called, when the instance of the class goes out of scope or it's memory released with the `delete` keyword. Destructor has a name, which starts from `~`.

In this particular case, this if the method `~VideoCapture`, which will be called in cases like:

```
// One case
{
VideoCapture vc;
} // <- here ~VideoCapture called as it goes out of scope

// Another one
VideoCapture *vc = new VideoCapture();
delete vc; //<- here ~VideoCapture called as it is being deleted

// One more
{
    std:unique_ptr<VideoCapture> vc = std::make_unique<VideoCapture>();
} // <- here ~VideoCapture called as its handler goes out of scope
```

Comment: ....Thanks for your answer...I had to choose ...but I upvoted your answer because  it taught me something too=)